# Supervised time series classification method for a system with both input and output time series sensor data

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, classification

Suppose there is a system and I want to classify whether the system is malfunctioning or not.
When the system is malfunctioning, the relationship between input and output is different from the normal case.

Ordinary supervised time series classification methods (RNN, DTW-kNN, etc.) would treat the input time series data and output time series data of the system equally.

However, if the time series data of the input and output of the system are explicitly separated, is there any supervised time series classification method that can improve the accuracy by using this information?